# macOS find: "relative path not safe", why?

Tags: macos, command-line, security, path, find

I'm running the following as part of my Travis CI build on macOS to delete all non-`.git` directories:

```
$ if [ "${TRAVIS_OS_NAME}" = "osx" ]; then find /usr/local/Homebrew \! -regex ".+\.git.+" -delete; fi
```

The output it gives is:

```
find: -delete: /usr/local/Homebrew: relative path potentially not safe
```

Why is my `/usr/local/Homebrew` path being considered a relative path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/497685/108618) on Unix & Linux SE:

> macOS `find` is based on an older version of FreeBSD `find` whose `-delete` would not remove the files that were given as argument.
>
> […]
>
> That was [changed in FreeBSD in 2013](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=253886), but the change apparently didn't make it to macOS.

Specifically in your case `/usr/local/Homebrew` is given as argument to `find`; therefore `-delete` cannot remove this exact object. The message `relative path potentially not safe` is misleading though. The [linked message](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=253886) sheds some light on what happens under the hood. It also states:

> Deleting the pathnames given as arguments can be prevented without error
>   messages using `-mindepth 1` or by changing directory and passing `.` as
>   argument to `find`.